# Historical music

Tags: pattern, visual, music

A song is represented by the changes you see, before you.  What song is it?
(I promise it's not too broad, just take a closer look.)

```
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
love love love love love love love love love love
```

## Clue:

$Press$ $Me$  $\mapsto$ <kbd>PLAY</kbd>

Comment: Okay, this is broader than I thought.  There's too many songs about love!  I'm adding a clue to narrow this down, further.

Comment: I'm not sure the hint [is as limiting as you think](https://musicbrainz.org/search?method=indexed&page=1&query=love*play&type=recording), but it's possible it's meant differently.

Comment: Definitely differently.   It refers to an aspect of the song other than its title.

Comment: I like this puzzle and I can see the way to solve it, but nothing is coming to mind yet and I'll probably have to start searching up some lyrics to confirm. :(

Comment: @Sleafar Worth noting:  Now that I'm home I checked that site (nice site, btw) and it does not have the information required to use the clue.  The song, however, does exist there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could be

> Only Love Remains, from the album "Press to Play".

Comment: Ah, good.  My updates to the "Play" button hint helped.  Good job. :)

Answer (score 7):

I think it's ...

> [Love Changes Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_Changes_Everything_%28song%29)

... because ...

> [all words change to "love"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/29954/revisions).

Comment: Closer - I honestly hadn't thought of that song.  The correct answer is slightly more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Just a variation:

> Love Conquers All

Because

> All the negative things in the first edit were replaced with love.

Comment: Great reasoning on this!  I've added a clue to try and fine tune what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> ["Love Remains the Same"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No8e0OE9QAU) by Gavin Rossdale?

because

> In all the words, love remains unchanged i.e. the same.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> All you need is LOVE by the beatles
> Because LOVE is all you need

Comment: Well, for this puzzle, you need the solution ;)

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> The power of love as it has replaced everything

Comment: No, sorry.  There's a lot of songs with "love" in them, but there's only one that accurately represents the progression.

Comment: Also, now I have that song stuck in my head...

Comment: i have listened it couple of times since morning as well

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't play for me so I'll take a wild guess

> Love Is Sweeping the Country by the Gershwins. From the comments it seems that the image should change from something else to all "love". What I see is an image with the work "love" written many times.

Comment: Check the edit history for explanation of why people are talking about it changing.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Tower of Love by Jim Noir

Comment: Haha, good guess, but how does it match the clue?

Comment: It looks somewhat like a tower....of love

Comment: Yes, it does, now.  But it didn't always.  :)  Check out the other answers =D

Comment: Welcome to SE Puzzling, btw - as a general habit, many of us try to be sure to give reasonings, during the answer, as to why we are making the answer that we are.  This ended up automatically flagged for review due to the small amount of content.  (In other words, SE didn't feel like this was a proper answer.)

Answer (score 0):

is it:

> Love is all you need by the beatles?

why:

> because the word love is said so many times?